# Automatically detect largest interval over which NDSolve can find a solution

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, automation, error-tracking

**Question**: Consider the following numerical resolution:

```
NDSolve[eqn, {x1[t], x2[t], y[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}
```

where `eqn`, `tmin` and `tmax` are given.

Suppose this gives an error (for example, a stiff system detection, or any numerical error).

How would you do to adjust *automatically* `tmin` and `tmax` to the largest (or a "large") interval where `NDSolve` doesn't give any error?

I tried using `Check` but I don't manage to use it efficiently as I cannot catch the defective times.

**Context**: In case you're wondering, I'm asking because I have a large number of odes `eqn` to solve, some of which work fine on $[t_\mathrm{min},t_\mathrm{max}]$, but some others don't. And of course I don't want to adjust the time interval by hand!

**Example**: With

```
eqn = {x1'[t] == -x1[t]^2 - x2[t] + y[t]^3, x2'[t] == x1[t] - x2[t] + x1[t]^2 x2[t]^2, 
y'[t] == x2[t]^2 + y[t] + x1[t]^2 y[t]^2 + 0.5` y[t]^3, x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 1, y[0] == 1};
```

the following

```
{tmin, tmax} = {-1, 1};
NDSolve[eqn, {x1[t], x2[t], y[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}];
```

yield an `NDSolve::ndsz` error while

```
{tmin, tmax} = {-0.5, 0.5};
NDSolve[eqn, {x1[t], x2[t], y[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}];
```

works fine.

Comment: Actually, `eqn` becomes stiff at `t~0.235`.
Have you tried Eventlocator?

Comment: I have, i did not managed to make it general (is it an upper or a lower bound, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NDSolve` has already detected the largest such intervals for you, which is why the resulting `InterpolatingFunction`s have restricted domains.  You can use `InterpolatingFunctionDomain` to extract those domains.  I'd do something like so

```
Clear[x1, x2, y]
eqn = {x1'[t] == -x1[t]^2 - x2[t] + y[t]^3, 
  x2'[t] == x1[t] - x2[t] + x1[t]^2 x2[t]^2, 
  y'[t] == x2[t]^2 + y[t] + x1[t]^2 y[t]^2 + 0.5` y[t]^3, x1[0] == 1,
 x2[0] == 1, y[0] == 1};
Quiet[
  {x1, x2, y} = NDSolveValue[eqn, {x1, x2, y}, {t, -1, 1}],
 NDSolveValue::ndsz]
```

[image]

Note that the domains are indicated as part of the result.  If you need to automatically extract them within code, you can do something like so

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
domains = InterpolatingFunctionDomain /@ {x1, x2, y}
{a, b} = {Min[#], Max[#]} &[Intersection[Interval @@@ domains]]
(* Out:
   {{{-0.720382, 0.234762}}, {{-0.720382, 0.234762}}, {{-0.720382, 0.234762}}}

   {-0.720382, 0.234762}
*)
```

Of course, the point is that you can use this in subsequent command without worrying about the problems arising from trying to use inputs from outside the domain of the `InterpolatingFunction`s.  For example, you can generate a plot.

```
ParametricPlot[{{x1[t], y[t]}, {x2[t], y[t]}}, {t, a, b}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. In a single `NDSolve` call like this, can't one assume that the domains of `x1, x2, y` will all be the same?

Comment: Perfect, with a few adjustements it worked (I'm on version 7), thank you. @MichaelE2: if think we can, and we save one line :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 You are probably right - I was clearly being paranoid. :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
thisstep = 0;
laststep = 0;
eqn = {x1'[t] == -x1[t]^2 - x2[t] + y[t]^3, 
 x2'[t] == x1[t] - x2[t] + x1[t]^2 x2[t]^2, 
  y'[t] == x2[t]^2 + y[t] + x1[t]^2 y[t]^2 + 0.5` y[t]^3, x1[0] == 1,
   x2[0] == 1, y[0] == 1};
{tmin, tmax} = {-1,1};

First@NDSolve[eqn, {x1[t], x2[t], y[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}, 
MaxStepFraction -> 1/150, 
StepMonitor :> (laststep = thisstep; thisstep = t;
  stepsize = thisstep - laststep;), 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    Method -> {"EventLocator", 
     "Event" :> (If[stepsize < 10^-4, 0, 1])}}
];
```

You might have to play around with minimum stepsize.

Comment: It yields the error `NDSolve::molpde` (because of "MethodOfLines"). But anyway I think it is easier to simply take the bounds from the output of NDSolve. Since this works, and do not investigate further. Thank you for your suggestion.